# Python passing entire list as argument without iterating over it?

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python and Pandas. Below is a part of code. When below was hardcoded its working correctly and generates expected json file. But when passing as arguments in function, its not generating any file. No error thrown. Even when I hardcode the i_indexList to [3,5,6,18,19] this is not working which means even i_fname and i_code is not getting passed correctly.

Need this as a function as multiple json files needs to be created whose names and content will be varying based on user input. Hence it cannot be hardcoded.

Please help with below:

1. What should be the return value to be mentioned in below marked Line X when the output is a .json file.
2. Is there any issue in the syntax of List passed as argument. (Line Y and Line Z)
3. Is this due to an indentation miss?

```
def json_file(i_fname, i_indexList, i_code):

    PathLink = os.path.join(path, i_fname + '.json') #Path Name Formation = os.path.join(path, 'test' + '.json') =C:/.../test.json     
    excel_data_df = pandas.read_excel('input.xlsx',
                                          sheet_name='input_sheet1',
                                          usecols=i_indexList , #starts from 0 ,i_indexList= [3,5,6,18,19]                                   
                                          dtype={'codenum': str})  # datatype is string for codenum column
    df_filtered = excel_data_df.loc[excel_data_df["codenum"]==i_code]    # Row Filtering = ["codenum"]=='AB123'
    print(df_filtered)         
    df_filtered.columns = ['Code', 'Student Name', 'Class', 'School Name','City Name'] #renaming 
    cols_to_keep = ['Student Name', 'Class', 'School Name','City Name'] # columns to keep
    df_filtered = df_filtered[cols_to_keep]  # columns to keep
    df_filtered                                # columns to keep
    json_str = df_filtered.to_json(PathLink,orient='records',indent=2) #json converted file    
    #? return what? return json_str? -- Line X
    
#1. Mapping as per user chooses
    if Priendpoint.get() == ' Code 1':
        #Function call to create json file 
        indexList=[3,5,6,18,19] --Line Y
        json_file('test', *indexList, 'codenum') --Line Z
```

Comment: Don't use `*`. That unpacks your `list` as arguments. Just call it with `json_file('test', indexList, 'codenum')`

Comment: @Axe319 Thank you .. removed the * . Could you please tell me if a return value is required for above function.

Comment: If you want to use `json_str` then yes, `return json_str` and change your call to `json_str = json_file('test', indexList, 'codenum')`.